# How to fix LOOP error PostgreSQL while trying to Select

Tags: sql, postgresql, loops

Here is the code I'm Testing :

```
DO $$
DECLARE 
    i INT := 0;
BEGIN
    WHILE i <= numberUsers
    BEGIN
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "Users";
        SET i := i + 1;
    END;
END $$;
```

But when I try to execute it it return me this error :

```
ERREUR:  « LOOP » manquant à la fin de l'expression SQL
LIGNE 7 :         SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "Users";
```

[image]

Kind Regards !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have considerable structural errors in your code block:

```
DO $$                       
DECLARE 
    i INT := 0;
BEGIN
    WHILE i <= numberUsers             --<<< numberUsers is undefined and uninitialized 
    BEGIN                              --<<< this starts a nested block should be LOOP
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "Users";  --<<< in a block you must tell plpgsql what to do with the result
        SET i := i + 1;                --<<< assignment does not use SET in plpgsql 
    END;                               --<<< terminated nested block, should terminate loop                           
END $$;
```

Correcting all the points from the block becomes:

```
do $$
declare 
    i int := 0;
    numberusers  int;
begin
    select count(*) 
      into numberusers
      from "users";
  
    while i <= numberusers
    loop
        i := i + 1;
    end loop;
end $$;
```

Comment: Hello !

I really like your answer it help me a lot but when I try your code I have an syntax error on the last line with "END $$;" Any ideas ?

Comment: I copied the code directly from my answer, ran it and got "SQL Error [42601]: "Unterminated dollar quote started at position 4 in SQL end $$;. Expected terminating $$". Looks like an unprintable character got between end and $$. Deleting and retyping that line fixed the problem. **Hint:** Never say you got an error. Always post the exact error message.

Answer (score 1):

Per:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONTROL-STRUCTURES-LOOPS

```
WHILE boolean-expression LOOP
    statements
END LOOP [ label ];
```

You need the `LOOP END ... LOOP` portions of the statement.

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you that something is missing from the expression, which is a clear indication that you have a syntax error. Try this code:

```
DO $$
DECLARE 
    i INT := 0;
BEGIN
    WHILE i <= numberUsers LOOP
    BEGIN
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "Users";
        SET i := i + 1;
    END LOOP;
END $$;
```

Read more here: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/plpgsql-while-loop/

Answer (score 0):

```
DO $$
BEGIN
DECLARE 
    i INT := 0;
    BEGIN
    WHILE i <= numberUsers LOOP
    
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "WU_Users";
        i := i + 1; 
    END LOOP;
END $$;
```

But it's returning me this now :

```
psql:matching.sql:12: ERREUR:  label de fin « matching » spécifié pour un bloc sans label
LIGNE 12 : END matching $$;
```